# Shift values in cells downwards when new values are added

Tags: excel, vba

This code reads values from an excel sheet and generates new values starting from row 54 because the content to read are in these rows (row 1 to 54). But at the moment, every time I re-execute, the code overwrite the previous data. What I want is for it to shift existing values downwards before putting the data there. For example, if I generate values to row 54 to row 70. If the function is ran again, it should shift this existing previous values to row 71 to row 87. Then insert the new values between row 54 and row 70.

```
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim NoTriangles As Variant

Dim X1 As Double
Dim X2 As Double
Dim X3 As Double
Dim X4 As Double

Dim Y1 As Double
Dim Y2 As Double
Dim Y3 As Double
Dim Y4 As Double
Dim SideBarTitles As Range

Dim n As Integer
X1 = Range("D26").Value
X2 = Range("D27").Value
X3 = Range("D28").Value
X4 = Range("D29").Value

Y1 = Range("E26").Value
Y2 = Range("E27").Value
Y3 = Range("E28").Value
Y4 = Range("E29").Value


Set SideBarTitles = Range("C26:C29")
StartRow = 54

NoTriangles = InputBox("How many Triangles?")

For n = 1 To NoTriangles - 3

   SideBarTitles.Copy Destination:=Range("C" & CStr(StartRow))

   'Range("C" + CStr(StartRow)) = SideBarTitles
   X1 = X1
   Range("D" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "X" + CStr(X1)
   Y1 = Y1 + 0.551
   Range("E" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "E" + CStr(Y1)
   StartRow = StartRow + 1

   X2 = X2 - 0.7
   Range("D" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "X" + CStr(X2)
   Y2 = Y2 - 0.29
   Range("E" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "E" + CStr(Y2)
   StartRow = StartRow + 1

   X3 = X3 + 0.704
   Range("D" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "X" + CStr(X3)
   Y3 = Y3 - 0.29
   Range("E" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "E" + CStr(Y3)
   StartRow = StartRow + 1

   X4 = X4
   Range("D" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "X" + CStr(X4)
   Y4 = Y4 + 0.551
   Range("E" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "E" + CStr(Y4)
   StartRow = StartRow + 2
Next n
```

Comment: You're not executing any insert command.You need to insert before the copy (1st line of your For Loop).  Try recording a macro that does what you want and work from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution. Add `Range("a54").EntireRow.Resize((NoTriangles - 3) * 5).Insert shift:=xlDown` before the loop(before `For` and after `Inputbox`) and it should insert (NoTriangles - 3)*5 rows after row 54. The reason to insert (NoTriangles - 3)*5 rows is that, based on your code, each execution of the loop generates 5 rows of values, and the loop will execute (NoTriangles - 3) times. You can change this to any number you like. Also, add the statement as it only if you are certain that the input will always be greater than 3, otherwise, add an if statement to exit the subroutine when `input` is less or equal to 3 to avoid error.

here is the complete code with insert command added.

```
Sub test()

Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim NoTriangles As Variant

Dim X1 As Double
Dim X2 As Double
Dim X3 As Double
Dim X4 As Double

Dim Y1 As Double
Dim Y2 As Double
Dim Y3 As Double
Dim Y4 As Double
Dim SideBarTitles As Range

Dim n As Integer
X1 = Range("D26").Value
X2 = Range("D27").Value
X3 = Range("D28").Value
X4 = Range("D29").Value

Y1 = Range("E26").Value
Y2 = Range("E27").Value
Y3 = Range("E28").Value
Y4 = Range("E29").Value


Set SideBarTitles = Range("C26:C29")
StartRow = 54

NoTriangles = InputBox("How many Triangles?")

Range("a54").EntireRow.Resize((NoTriangles - 3) * 5).Insert shift:=xlDown

For n = 1 To NoTriangles - 3

   SideBarTitles.Copy Destination:=Range("C" & CStr(StartRow))

   'Range("C" + CStr(StartRow)) = SideBarTitles
   X1 = X1
   Range("D" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "X" + CStr(X1)
   Y1 = Y1 + 0.551
   Range("E" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "E" + CStr(Y1)
   StartRow = StartRow + 1

   X2 = X2 - 0.7
   Range("D" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "X" + CStr(X2)
   Y2 = Y2 - 0.29
   Range("E" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "E" + CStr(Y2)
   StartRow = StartRow + 1

   X3 = X3 + 0.704
   Range("D" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "X" + CStr(X3)
   Y3 = Y3 - 0.29
   Range("E" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "E" + CStr(Y3)
   StartRow = StartRow + 1

   X4 = X4
   Range("D" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "X" + CStr(X4)
   Y4 = Y4 + 0.551
   Range("E" + CStr(StartRow)).Value = "E" + CStr(Y4)
   StartRow = StartRow + 2
Next n
End Sub
```